# How to respond based on received action in Web API 2 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How would I create one controller with one API link in Web API 2 ASP.NET to respond on received data by an action that is in that data?

For example I receive this data:

> `{"t":"868efd5a8917350b63dfe1bd64","action":"getExternalServicePar","args":
>       {"id":"4247f835bb59b80"}}`

and now I need to respond based on this "action" value. If there is some other action value like "incrementVallet" I need to respond with different data, and all that from one API link, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious question to ask is "Why would you want to do that?". Why not multiple methods or even multiple controllers? Having said that, you could do the following if you really want to:

```
public class ActionDetails 
{
    public string t { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public ArgsContainer args { get; set; }
}
public ArgsContainer 
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Controller and method:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    // POST is not really the right choice for operations that only GET something
    // but if you want to pass an object as parameter you really don't have much of a choice
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage DoSomeAction(ActionDetails details)
    {
        // prepare the result content
        string jsonResult = "{}";
        switch (details.action) 
        {
            case "getExternalServicePar":
                var action1Result = GetFromSomewhere(details.args.id); // do something
                jsonResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(action1Result);
                break;
            case "incrementVallet":
                var action2Result = ...; // do something else
                jsonResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(action2Result);
                break;
        }
        // put the serialized object into the response (and hope the client knows what to do with it)
        var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(jsonResult, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return response;
    }
}
```